# Appeal for refused visa to Norway

Tags: visas, visa-refusals, norway, afghan-citizens

Is it possible to appeal directly to the Norwegian Directorate of Immigration (UDI), rather than the Embassy?

The Embassy of Norway in Islamabad is really weird. I called many times, and they don't answer my phone calls and or respond to my emails. They rejected my visa on the basis that I am a threat to the security or public health.

However, I was applying for a visa Schengen as the spouse of a European citizen. I am am an Afghan citizen married to a Polish woman who has lived in Norway for 4 years.

Comment: You should ask a Norwegian immigration lawyer what to do.

Comment: http://www.skillsyouneed.com/write/punctuation1.html

Comment: You'd better ask this [here](http://law.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 3):

According to the [**Norwegian Directorate of Immigration (UDI)**](https://www.udi.no/en/word-definitions/appealing-a-decision/#link-6626)

> If an embassy has made the decision in your application, you must hand in the appeal to this embassy.
>
> **Who can appeal?**
>
> You who are appealing, must either be the applicant yourself (the person who wish to visit or live in Norway), or have been given power-of-attorney/authorisation by the applicant.
>
> If you are the applicant's family member, employer or friend in Norway and wish to appeal, you must therefore have been given power-of-attorney/authorisation by the applicant.
>
> **What is the deadline for appealing?**
>
> You must appeal within three weeks from the date on which you, your authorised representative or your lawyer received the decision or when you should have become aware of the decision.
>
> Have you not managed to obtain all the documentation you wish to enclose with your appeal within the three-week deadline? You must in any case submit your appeal within the deadline, but you can write in the appeal that you wish to send us more documentation. You will then be given a new deadline of two weeks to submit the documentation.
>
> **How do you appeal?**
>
> 1. Write a letter where you explain which decision you are appealing and why you believe the decision you have received is incorrect. The letter must be written in Norwegian or English.
> 2. Sign the letter.
> 3. Send the letter to the embassy. If you have any new information or documentation, you must enclose it.
>
> It does not cost anything to appeal.
>
> **How long will it take before your appeal is decided?**
>
> See information about [case processing times](https://www.udi.no/en/word-definitions/case-processing-times/).
>
> **What happens when you appeal a decision?**
>
> 1. When you appeal, the embassy will reconsider your case.
> 2. The embassy can either grant your appeal or forward it to the UDI for consideration.
> 3. The UDI will consider your case again, and either reject or grant your appeal.
> 4. If the UDI also rejects your appeal, there are no other possibilities of appeal.